# Wordpress loop query not working

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am wondering what I am doing wrong when using WP_Query()

I have my array of arguments that I am passing to WP_Query() but the results coming back are not what I was expecting.

```
            <?php $args = array(
                "paged" => get_query_var('page'),
                "posts_per_page" => 10,
                "order" => "DESC"

            ); ?>
            <?php $blogPosts = new WP_Query($args); ?>
            <?php if( $blogPosts->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php while ( $blogPosts->have_posts() ) : $blogPosts->the_post(); ?>
                <article>
                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                    <?php the_date('M. j, Y'); ?><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </article>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The results I am getting, display all of my posts and apparently in no certain order, although I am saying descending by date.  Also, some of the posts being returned have no output for the

ON TOP OF THIS, when I add the following array element to the array of $args

```
"category__not_in" => array(5),//also tried "post__not_in" => 5
```

So now the array looks like this:

```
            <?php $args = array(
                "category__not_in" => array(5),//also tried "post__not_in" => 5
                "paged" => get_query_var('page'),
                "posts_per_page" => 10,
                "order" => "DESC"
            ); ?>
```

This fails to remove any of the posts that fall into that category.

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't look like there is anything particularly wrong with this. Are you sure you're calling it on the right page (perhaps your page is using a different template)? Also, post__not_in excludes _posts_, not categories. Use _category__not_in_ if you want to exclude posts from a certain category.

Comment: Thank you for the correct argument name, I changed that and I still am not getting the correct results.  It's very frusterating, still getting all the posts from category 5.

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? WP < 3.0.2. should use `get_query_var( 'paged' )` [doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: I am using 3.3, so it's "page", I looked into that myself.  Thanks though Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php $args = array(
    "paged" => get_query_var('page'),
    "posts_per_page" => 10,
    "cat" => -5,
    "orderby" => "date",
    "order" => "DESC"
); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, believe it or not this is not working still.  The results of the above are not doing anything different, however; if I change the "cat"=>-5 to "cat"=>5 then I get just the ones in category 5 hahaha but -5 returns all my posts.  This almost seems like it's a bug in wordpress cause I can not find a fix for it.

Comment: Try with '-5', as it was a string.